# How to update the value entered in the textfield in react native to API?

Tags: react-native

Below is my textfield which gets pre-filled if the API gives any data.

Now, I want to update the value to API after it gets changed so that it gets changed everywhere. How do I do it?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ListView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from "react-native";
import StepIndicator from "react-native-step-indicator"; // 0.0.9
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-material-dropdown";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Left,
  Body,
  Right,
  Button,
  Title,
  Icon,
  Thumbnail
} from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import CardView from "react-native-cardview";
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';


export default class refill3 extends Component {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safecontainer}>
          <Header
            style={{
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
              backgroundColor: "#FEFEFE",
              borderColor: "transparent",
              shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
              shadowOpacity: 0
            }}
            borderWidth={0}
            backgroundColor={"##C91F35"}
            androidStatusBarColor={"#FEFEFE"}
            iosBarStyle={"dark-content"}
            noShadow={true}
          >
            <Left style={{ flex: 0 }}>
              <Button
                transparent
                onPress={() =>
                  this.props.screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate("Refill2")
                }
              >
                <Icon
                  name="ios-arrow-round-back"
                  size={38}
                  style={{ fontSize: 38, color: "#000" }}
                />
              </Button>
            </Left>

            <Body style={styles.body}>
              <Title style={{ color: "#000", paddingLeft: 5 }}>Checkout</Title>
            </Body>

            <Right style={{ flex: 1 }} />
          </Header>

          <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.stepIndicator}>
              <StepIndicator
                customStyles={stepIndicatorStyles}
                stepCount={4}
                direction="horizontal"
                currentPosition={this.state.currentPage}
              />
            </View>

            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                paddingLeft: 20,
                paddingRight: 20
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#C3152D",
                  top: 50,
                  color: "#C3152D",
                  width: 5
                }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 19,
                  letterSpacing: 0.01,
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 4,
                  top: 50,
                  color: "black",
                  fontWeight: "bold"
                }}
              >
                Billing Address
              </Text>
            </View>


              <View
                style={{
                  top: 0,
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  padding:0
                }}
              >


              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 19,
                  letterSpacing: 0.01,
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 0,
                  paddingRight: 0,
                  marginTop: 90,
                  color: "black",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  height: 25
                }}
              >
                Country
              </Text>



                <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                           value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.country_code} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false} />

              </View>



              <View
                style={{
                  top: 0,
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  padding:0
                }}
              >


              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 19,
                  letterSpacing: 0.01,
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 0,
                  paddingRight: 0,
                  marginTop: 20,
                  color: "black",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  height: 25
                }}
              >
                First Name
              </Text>



                <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                           value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.first_name} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

              </View>



            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              Last Name
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.last_name} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>



            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              Street Address
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.street_address} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>





            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              City
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.city} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>



            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              Postal Code
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} keyboardType='numeric' textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.postal_code} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>



            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              State
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.state} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>



            <View
              style={{
                top: 0,
                marginLeft: 20,
                marginRight: 20,
                padding:0
              }}
            >


            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 19,
                letterSpacing: 0.01,
                margin: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                marginTop: 20,
                color: "black",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                height: 25
              }}
            >
              Order Comments
            </Text>



              <TextField style={{ color: '#000', marginTop: 0, fontSize:18, height: 30, padding:0}} textAlignVertical='top' baseColor = '#C91F35' tintColor = '#C91F35' 
                         value={global.CheckOutData.billing_address.order_comment} editable={true} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>

            </View>

            <View style={[styles.lineStyle4]} />

            <View style={{ top: 50, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 12,
                  letterSpacing: 0.01,
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 2,
                  left: 0,
                  top: 20,
                  color: "#6B727A"
                }}
              >
                This is Step 3 of 3. In the next page you can review your order
                and product information
              </Text>
            </View>


              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  top: 100,
                  paddingLeft: 20,
                  paddingRight: 20,
                  zIndex: 1
                }}
              >
                <View style={{ width: "50%", height: 50, top: 10, zIndex: 1 }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                      width: 155,
                      height: 50,
                      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      borderRadius: 3,
                      zIndex: 1
                    }}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate(
                        "Dashboard"
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 18,
                        paddingLeft: 10,
                        color: "#706F70",
                        textDecorationLine: "underline"
                      }}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={{ width: "50%", height: 70, top: 10 }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                      width: 155,
                      height: 50,
                      backgroundColor: "#C91F35",
                      position: "absolute",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      borderRadius: 3,
                      zIndex: 1
                    }}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate(
                        "Refill4"
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        alignSelf: "center",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        top: "0%"
                      }}
                    >
                      Review Your Order
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>


            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "column"
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ width: "100%", height: 210 }} />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  letterSpacing: 0.01,
                  margin: 0,
                  paddingLeft: 2,
                  left: 0,
                  top: 50,
                  color: "#6B727A"
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  getVisibleRows = visibleRows => {
    const visibleRowNumbers = Object.keys(visibleRows.s1).map(row =>
      parseInt(row)
    );
    this.setState({ currentPage: visibleRowNumbers[0] });
  };
}


});
```

Above is the updated code of the activity where all the details gets prefilled from the API. If the user makes any edit, after clicking the button, it should save by which it will be updated globally.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `TextField`, why not using `TextInput` ?

Comment: What version of React Native are you running?

Comment: Yes @oma . I am using Material design Textfield..

Comment: @Ismailp Its is 0.56.0

Comment: I tried doing this, but It didn't work - onChangeText={(country_code) => this.setState({country_code})}

Comment: @Abhishek is it a specific npm package? Material Desing TextField? Could you provide a URL to the package in that case?

Comment: @Abhishek could you also update your question with more code. Would be helpful to see the complete component.

Comment: @Ismailp Here is the package URL - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-textinput

Comment: @Ismailp, I have updated the code. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to update the API when you need to implement the `onChangeText` functionality of that specific package. See an example of this below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  TextField
} from 'react-native-material-textfield';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleInputChange = this._handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {};
  }

  _handleInputChange(value) {
    // Send request via API to save the value in DB
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        label='Country code'
        value={ global.CheckOutData.billing_address.country_code }
        onChangeText={ this._handleInputChange }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

After saving the value via the API you need to make sure that `global.CheckOutData.billing_address.country_code` gets updated as well, otherwise you won't see the new value in the TextField. This is usually handled by implementing a state manager for your application. I usually implement [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for that to keep everything in-sync.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In react-native-material-textfield, 'value' prop acts as default. To update the value you need to use ref. Get the ref using React.createRef(), then use setValue function from ref.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
  textField = React.createRef<TextField>();
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'check',
    };
  }

  onChangeText = () => {
    // Send request via API to save the value in DB
  };

  updateText = () => {
    if (this.textField && this.textField.current) {
      this.textField.current.setValue('test');
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextField
          label="Test value"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          ref={this.textField}
        />
        <Button onPress={this.updateText} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TextField } from 'react-native-material-textfield';

                            <TextField
                                containerStyle={styles.textInputStyle}
                                label="Email"
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.onEmailTextChange(text)} />
```